# Unknown authentication strategy passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js, mean-stack

I have setup a MEAN.IO app using the base template and am attempting to add Windows Live and Yahoo passport authentication dependencies.

I have npm installed both dependencies and set up the code (see below) just like the other passport schemes like Facebook and Google (which came pre-installed and are working).

---

passport.js:

```
YahooStrategy = require('passport-yahoo-oauth').Strategy,
WindowsLiveStrategy = require('passport-windowslive').Strategy,
GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy,
```

---

```
// Use windows live strategy
    passport.use(new WindowsLiveStrategy({
        clientID: config.strategies.windowslive.clientID,
        clientSecret: config.strategies.windowslive.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: config.strategies.windowslive.callbackURL
      },
      function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        User.findOne({
          'windowslive.id': profile.id
        }, function(err, user) {
          if (user) {
            return done(err, user);
        }
        user = new User({
          name: profile.displayName,
          email: profile.emails[0].value,
          username: profile.emails[0].value,
          provider: 'windowslive',
          windowslive: profile._json,
          roles: ['authenticated']
        });
        user.save(function(err) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Windows Live login failed, email already used by other login strategy'});
          } else {
            return done(err, user);
          }
        });
      });
    }
  ));
```

---

user routes (server/users/routes.js)

```
// Setting the windows live oauth routes
app.route('/api/auth/windowslive')
  .get(passport.authenticate('windowslive', {
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    scope: ['wl.signin','wl.basic']
  }), users.signin);

app.route('/api/auth/windowslive/callback')
  .get(passport.authenticate('windowslive', {
    failureRedirect: '/login'
  }), users.authCallback);
```

I keep getting Error: Unknown authentication strategy "windowslive" and Error: Unknown authentication strategy "yahoo" however the facebook and google routes work fine. Any idea why? Are there any other steps needed to configure new Passport strategies?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding this to your passport.use statement:

```
passport.use('windowslive', new WindowsLiveStrategy({
...
```